# How do I limit the number of digits in a list?

Tags: python, list, formatting

This is a small piece of code that I am writing for an chemistry ab initio program. I am having issues making the C1pos list a number with exactly 6 digits after the decimal place. I have tried several methods such as the decimal function, but so far I am having no luck.

Position is a definition that will take a matrix (1,1,1)+(1,1,1) and give you (2,2,2) numpy is not installed on my server.

```
class Position:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)  

    def __add__(self, other):

        data = [] #start with an empty list

        for j in range(len(self.data)):

            data.append(self.data[j] + other.data[j])

        return Position(data) 


deltaa=2.000001
#Set number of steps +1
numx=2
numy=1
numz=1
Carbon=[1.070000,0.000000,0.000000]
startpos=[1.000000,1.000000,1.000000]
l=[]
top=os.getcwd()
lgeom=[]
for i in range(numx):
    for j in range(numy):
        for h in range(numz):
            l=i, j, h
            shift=list(l)
            shiftdist=[ k*deltaa for k in shift] 
            C1pos=Position(Carbon)+Position(shiftdist)+Position(startpos)
            ltempl[10]=' C1,'+str(C1pos).strip('[]').replace(' ','')
```

Any suggestions?

EG: The output needs to be C1,2.123456,3.123456,4.123456  The number will never surpass 10.

Comment: Its a definition that will add matrices (1,1,1)+(1,1,1)=(2,2,2)

Comment: thank you, but what Position(Carbon) is supposed to give ?

Comment: So Position() must have two parameters, uh ?

Comment: Sorry Position is a class I added it to the main post.

Comment: This is my first program so that was code that I found. It seems to work just fine. ltempl is a sample input that I am stripped into a list. I am replacing values of that list to create many files with different geometries.

Comment: I think you can replace the code block of __add__ with **return Position([self.data[j] + other.data[j] for j in range(len(self.data))])**

Comment: I think you doesn't need **l** nor **shift**. The instruction **shiftdist=[ k*deltaa for k in (i,j,h)]** should be enough

Comment: I don't really understand how that will help me as the Position class is not the problem unless it is doing something with the data that I do not understand.

Comment: My remarks are not to solve your problem; J.F.Sebastian has given the solution. My remarks are only to improve your code: why defining an object that is not necessary ? It slows down the execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
','.join("%.6f" % f for f in C1pos)
```

#### Example

```
C1pos = [2.123, 300.123456, 4.123456789]
print ','.join("%.6f" % f for f in C1pos)
```

#### Output

```
2.123000,300.123456,4.123457
```

Comment: When I try this I get:  TypeError: iteration over non-sequence         Even when just using the print function.

Comment: @Ophion: I guess you're using your Position class. Define `__iter__` on it like `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.data)`

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you! I think I got a bit over my head when I started to deal with classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the decimal class to round all your numbers to 6 decimal places.

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP

Decimal(n).quantize(Decimal('.000001'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

or if you are doing this operation on a string (as i suspect from your code):

```
print ('C1,' + ','.join(["%.6f" %x for x in C1pos]))
```